# Yii2: unable to change CKeditor content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, yii2

So, I created CKeditor via Yii2:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'content')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
            'options' => ['rows' => 6],
            'preset' => 'full',
        ])->label(false) ?>
```

This is the generated HTML code (plus select element, I'll explain its purpose right after this):

```
<select id="newsletterform-template" class="form-control" name="NewsletterForm[template]">
<option value="1">first option</option>
<option value="2">second option</option>
</select>

<textarea id="newsletterform-content" name="NewsletterForm[content]" rows="6"></textarea>
```

and now, when I change the value of select element, I want to dynamically change content of the CKeditor using jQuery. Problem is, none of the solutions I've tried so far, seems to work. 
Neither:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#newsletterform-template").change(function() {
    $("#newsletterform-content").val("something");
  });
</script>
```

or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  CKEDITOR.instances.NewsletterForm[content].setData('<p>This is the editor data.</p>');
</script>
```

This, however, changes content of the CKeditor, but it doesn't solve my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#newsletterform-content").val("something");
</script>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: "*This, however, changes content of the CKeditor, but it doesn't solve my problem...*" **What Problem ??**

Comment: That I need to change CKeditor's content after I change the select element, not right after the page loads, which is what the last script does.

Comment: can you make sure that your `.change()` event is being attached and triggered properly, do some log or alert may be.

Comment: yeah, I also tried that, alert did actually work, but CKeditor still remains unchanged

Comment: Are you using the jQuery adaptor?

Comment: If this is what you mean: `<script src="/mailer/web/assets/76d86832/adapters/jquery.js"></script>` then yes, it's among the included scripts